# Why do idle elevators close the doors?

Tags: physical, efficiency

If the elevator stops on a floor, opens the doors to let the passengers out, and hasn't received a command to go on another floor, why does it close its doors afterwards?

If the elevator is *not* on my current floor then I can understand the reason you'd want to have the elevator doors remain closed - however if the elevator is already on my floor - it seems like closing the doors at that point is adding unnecessary time.

Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: My old dentists office had physical doors which could only be opened when the elevator was on that floor (some kind of locking mechanism).

Comment: Not all elevators behave like that.  I've seen elevators that keep the door open when on the ground floor, where many people want to enter.

Comment: There are elevators which don't have doors at all... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternoster So the question could be rephrased about the need for having user operated doors in the first place rather than an automatic guard or fitting the inside of the elevator shelf at the door side with a seemless, low friction material.

Comment: Actually, the usual duty of an elevator is to carry people one way and return empty.  In the morning most people go up, in the evening most go down.  To me, the normal thing to do would be to close the doors and go back to where they were last called.

Comment: See also related question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36497/elevator-dispatch-algorithm-choice

Comment: "open doors" = "broken/currently serviced elevator"

Comment: @FlorianF That would waste energy. If the lift started on the ground floor(floor 0) and went up to floor 4, then went back to the ground floor before being called up to floor 2 it would pass through a total of 10 floors (0>4 = 4 changes, 4>0 = 4 changes, 0>2 = 2 changes). If the lift stayed where it was when people got off, the journey would then be ground floor to floor 4, then to floor 2, which is only 6 floor changes. It might make sense in a smaller building, but it's still got the potential to waste energy.

Comment: @Pharap: more important than optimizing energy for elevator algorithm is to optimize for travel latency/delay (between request to arrival) and starvations/fairness (can't have people in the top-most floor always being the slowest to serve). In busy offices where the direction of travel is highly asymmetric during different times, elevators may be programmed to have most of the cars wait in the ground floor in the morning when most people are going up and to spread across higher floors in the evening where most people are going down.

Comment: @LieRyan It's wasted energy and time. If someone calls the lift to floor 6 from floor 0, then the next call is from floor 8, the time spent travelling 8 floors is less than had it just stayed at floor 6. Though technically it would probably make more sense that the lift should always return to the centre of the building so it takes equal time to reach the top floor or the ground floor.

Comment: @Pharap: in most places, the entrees and exitees are not uniformly distributed but rather follow a predictable pattern. Suppose that you know that at certain hour, 95% of users will be coming from GF going to a uniformly distributed destination and the 5% are uniformly distributed; if the lift waits on its last destination floor, then 95% of people would have to wait for the lift to move N levels (N/2 to go to GF and N/2 to go to their destination). OTOH, if the lift has a home floor, 95% of people only have to wait for an average of N/2 floors. Also lifts needs to accelerate to speed.

Comment: @Pharap: another case, suppose a really famous restaurant is in the penthouse of an otherwise sleepy office building. Most people eating there are outsiders coming from GF, rather than the office workers. During lunch time, it would make sense to always have one lift stationed on the penthouse and one on GF, as probabilistically those are the highest traffic area. Also, serving the penthouse the fastest will probably leave the lift with room to spare to pick up passengers from other floor, while additional delay on those floors can mean that the lifts will always be full on GF and penthouse.

Comment: @gerrit is right, some elevators will leave the door open on the ground floor so that people can just walk in, but on other floors it'd be less common for people to walk up to the elevator on the non lobby floors.

Comment: [It's more complicated than that](ftp://files.killco.com/Production/09-926%20Mohegan%20Sun/Close-Out/Subcontractors%20Operation%20and%20Maintenance/Division%2014/Otis%20Elevator%20Company-PA/Gen2%20Owners%20Manual.pdf), says the manual for Otis elevators

Comment: @Florian - In home buildings, it is the contrary. In the morning most people go down. And in the evening most people go up.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very good question. Interestingly, the lifts with a manual outer door leave their inner door open when idle. The manual outer door typically has a window. The automatic lifts in the Paris métro and RER keep their doors open when waiting. These both cases offer the advantage of seeing whether the lift is there.

Comment: The fact that the doors always close when the elevator is idle makes it hard to air it out when a smoker has just taken it directly after cigarette break outside.  So I end up punching all the buttons at once, hoping the repeated open/close will perform the same function.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

A Google search doesn't really provide me any answers but I do have some ideas on why the doors would close:

**1: Time Efficiency** (As stated by Andrew, Ruudt, and Angelo)
Closing the door reduces the time the elevator needs, to move to a different floor when someone presses the button.

**2: Safety (1)**
When a door stays open and a user approaches the elevator, the door could close at the moment when the user enters the elevator, which could cause a problematic situation. Opening a door on request, lets the elevator know there is someone who wants to enter.

**3: Safety (2)**
Generally elevators have double doors. One on the elevator itself and one on each floor, that opens whenever the elevator is at the right floor. To prevent people from falling down the shaft, both doors open at the exact same time via a mechanism. Keeping the doors open could possibly pose a hazard here of having the outer doors stay open while the elevator is not on the same floor.

**4: Safety (3)**
Young kids, pets or wild animals are less likely to manage entering the elevator while it waits, since they won't be able to press the button.

**5: Energy Efficiency**
Elevators tend to turn off the light when it is still waiting a new user to save energy. An open elevator with the lights off (to conserve energy) would give off the impression of a broken elevator, even if the lights were to turn on whenever a user steps in the elevator. Closing the doors and turning off the lights doesn't have this problem.

Disclaimer: I don't have research to back this up unfortunately. Just my two cents here.

**Edit to conclude my list of reasons**

It occurred to me that the main reason for closing the doors is an historical/cultural thing. Originally, doors were put in an elevator to prevent people from falling down the shaft. It's inventors weren't necessarily concerned about speed and efficiency; just safety. (Late 1800's)

Currently the main purpose of elevator doors still is safety. And although we have improved the technology over time, an open elevator poses possible threats because of faulty technology. Furthermore, it could also be perceived as more dangerous because we are not used to it.

Closing an elevator door is consistent with the behavior we believe is normal since that is the way they have been since the introduction of elevator doors. Keeping it open could induce a feeling of insecurity when entering the elevator.

Comment: point 5 is quite interesting! a pet could accidentally enter an otherwise empty elevator and end up lost at another floor.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain I buy the 4th point.  How does the elevator know no one is in the elevator?

Comment: @nhgrif - I once entered an elevator deep in my thoughts and forgot to press button to go up. In 10 or 20 seconds the lights and fan went off. Elevator does not need to "know". An inactivity timer works just fine.

Comment: I don't buy point 2 (Safety 1). If elevator doors close within a limited timespan after opening, the probability that the doors close right when someone tries to walk through is even higher than that of entering an open elevator at the same moment as the elevator happens to be called on another floor. Just think of elderly or otherwise slow people, multi-elevator systems where you have to bridge a few meters from the central calling button to the farthest elevator, or large groups of people who do not make it in time through the elevator doors.

Comment: @nhgrif - I wonder if some lifts might know that they are occupied by the weight increase (all lifts will check they are not overloaded before moving, and alert/alarm if they are overloaded anyway, so weight must be measured!)

Comment: Most elevators have sensors that detect when a hand or other object goes between the doors.  Older elevators had a bar that acted as a switch so the door would have to close on you to activate the switch.  Both systems sometimes work poorly.  I've had an elevator try to close on me 20+ stories up... not fun.

Comment: @ O.R. Mapper: Point 2 is indeed minor but it is still a valid reason for shutting the door. As a user you know that when the door opens on request, or you see someone entering the elevator, you have x seconds to enter before the doors try to close. If the doors are always open you never really know when they will close. The behavior becomes unpredictable. If the sensors work poorly/slow this could mean that you get hit by the doors before they open up again.

Comment: I like point 4, imagine calling the elevator, it reaches your floor and a velociraptor charges out! You'd be wishing they didn't keep the doors open on the Jurassic floor for sure.

Comment: What about the case of a creepiness factor. I mean have you had to ride an elevator without doors? (Service Elevator or the like) when it reached each individual floor I got very anxious about the possibility of something going wrong. Granted, I'm afraid of heights, so seeing the actual walls in between each floor had an eeriness to it.

Comment: Even if it could be easily implemented (since elevators have scales), I doubt point 5 *-the edited one-* is right... I believe in most modern elevators the lights are always on. This can be easily proven since many elevators use fluorescent lights which may take a while to turn on, and you don't see them turning on when the gates open on pressing the button (if the elevator is already on your floor). A waste of energy? yes... but also reality.

Comment: @QuestionMarcs I guess that's something people would get used to. In my country, it's not that uncommon to see elevators with no or malfunctioning inner doors. Also almost all elevators have windows on inner doors, so you can see the wall in any case and I've never heard anyone of commenting that it's distracting to take a ride in such elevator.

Comment: I can tell you that elevators don't turn off the lights when idle (lights are required to be on), however do actually turn off the fans inside.

Comment: Safety 2 is moot. An elevator cab will never take off unless both doors are closed, and having the inner door closing while the outer door stays open is mechanically impossible (there is no motor on the outer door, when the cab is on the floor the inner door's mechanism also moves the outer door).

Comment: @AndréDaniel However, what if the sensor fails? If the door is closed by default, both these things would have to happen to have the door open after the elevator has left: (1) the functioning motor would have to suddenly open the door, (2) the door sensor would have to fail. With the door open by default, only one of these need to happen.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Depends on the country I think.

Comment: @yo' there are two separate sensors for the outer and inner door, if one fails its signal won't match the other's signal and the elevator's controller wouldn't allow the cab to move. Also I believe the door locking mechanism itself can give feedback and the controller can know whether the door locked successfully.

Comment: This is a really good answer, but @Kent's answer below makes a great point that isn't covered here: What happens if you've just walked in to an already-open elevator, haven't pressed a button yet, and it gets called elsewhere?  It's a classic race condition, albeit on a much slower scale than software usually has to handle.

Comment: About the point 2 : A lift that closes its doors can also have someone walking in at the time of closing. And the person often walks in without pushing the button, so the lift does not know that someone wants to come in. A person coming in while the lift is closing is a common situation that lifts usually are able to handle.

Comment: The point 4 can be a good reason for cats and children. On the other hand, requiring the person to push the button can be an annoyance. When the person is old, or has many packs, or is moving furniture...

Comment: Regarding the point 4 : Closing the doors can be *a false good idea*. If the doors stay open, the cat or child can come in, but then s/he can go out, especially when the light goes off. Now, if the doors close, the cat or child has a smaller risk of going in, but s/he can go in anyway, and then s/he has a big risk of being trapped inside and ending up later at another floor.

Comment: @GWv - With a lift keeping its doors open, if you were the anxious type, you could always begin with pushing the button. Thus, you would be sure that the lift would not close on you.

Comment: @Tsasken - I like your remark ! [People must always take velociraptors into account when designing things.](http://xkcd.com/87/)

Comment: The point 5 is not valid. If a user thinks that an unlit lift is broken, it is a user problem. Some people think that because lifts do close their doors. If lifts work differently, people think differently. For instance, lifts with a manual outer door typically have a window on the outer door, leave their inner door open and turn their light off after a while. People take them anyway. People coming in an unlit flat don't think the flat is broken.

Answer (score 130):

Closing the door for the floor the elevator is on reduces the time, the elevator can serve another floor upon request. The time is saved due to omitting the door closing step.

Considering that elevators usually serve more than two floors this speeds up the more frequent use case.

Comment: Yeah, assuming all floors have an equal chance of needing to be used then the chance of the floor the lift is at being needed is 1/x whilst the chance of another floor needing it is x-1/x.... which is at the worst (2 story building) is equal to 1/x, most likely its significantly more.

Comment: As an addition to this, some elevator systems will actually move the elevator while not in use to a more centrally located floor. This potentially decreases the response time further as the elevator is more likely to be close to the user.

Comment: @DanielCook And I've encountered multiple two-elevator systems that send one to the top and one to the bottom when idle.

Comment: There are elevator systems where you have to preselect your desired floor when requesting the elevator, and the computer calculates which elevator to send. Some even have not a single elevator that serves all floors.

Comment: @DanielCook There's usually *almost* twice the probability of an elevator being called on the ground floor than it is to be called on "every other floor", so central floors would make less sense than ground floor for a standing elevator in this case.

Comment: @jcl That would likely vary greatly upon the time of day and may be building specific. In my building people frequently change floors for meetings without returning to the ground floor.

Comment: Definitely, that's why I used "almost"... the most frequent use of an elevator (yes, except in some specific buildings) is getting from the ground floor to an elevated floor and back. Still, I'm sure the ground floor is more used even in those specific buildings: *everyone* not using stairs would use the ground floor on it... not everyone would change floors

Comment: I wonder if any elevators use machine learning to determine the most probable location to idle in order to reduce the wait based on the time of day.

Comment: @Keavon I personally doubt it. Not that I have proof, or that there could not be a "very specialized" elevator that does it... but general commercial elevators? pretty much doubtful.

Comment: @Keavon Some interesting tidbits here, maybe it is being done: http://www.smartelevators.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=105&Itemid=97 _More advanced programs take passenger traffic patterns into account. They know which floors have the highest demand, at what time of day, and direct the elevator cars accordingly. In a multiple car system, the elevator will direct individual cars based on the location of other cars..._

Comment: @tobii Though that can be solved using simple statistics, rather than the much more elaborate techniques in machine learning. Break the week into (say) 336 half-hour chunks, and for each store a count of each pair from/to floor. That only needs a few kilobytes of stable storage, which is trivial even for a microcontroller. Use that to select an appropriate floor on which to wait at any given weekday and time. I'm sure you can make it plenty more elaborate than that, but that definitely is not *machine learning* like Keavon talked about.

Comment: @theotherone - (x-1)/x

Comment: @Alexander - I have never seen a lift asking for the wanted floor at calling time. But often there are two calling buttons, one for going up and one for going down.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco In the German "Post Tower" skyscraper in Bonn, you have to tell the system at calling time where you want to go. I saw it myself and also rode in it.

Answer (score 23):

There are several answers about reducing time for people calling the elevator from other floors, however while desirable, I believe that is a secondary benefit.

**Safety trumps convenience.**

Typically, automatic door closure is related to an emergency situation.

An example might be that a fire (possibly as yet undetected) has occurred on a floor , or hot or noxious gases are present for whatever reason at one level of the building.

Automatically closing the doors reduces the potential movement of smoke and/or gases into the lift, so that if the lift is called from another floor, the gases will not be brought from elsewhere only to flow out over unwitting waiters. This may include the possibility of the fire entering the lift itself.

This eventuality may still occur before fires or other issues have been detected and therefore prior to emergency procedures coming into effect.

---

**EDIT** Someone mentioned they've seen elevator doors remain open when on the ground floor.

This actually still fits the fire safety scenario, for example according to [Schindler's Emergency Operation of Elevator Systems](http://www.schindler.com/content/us/internet/en/service-maintenance/_jcr_content/rightPar/downloadlist/downloadList/189_1336163651964.download.asset.189_1336163651964/cmn1028emergops.pdf) (yeah Schindler's Lifts!):

> If a smoke sensor is tripped, either above or below the main lobby,
>   all cars in that bank will recall, running nonstop to the main egress
>   level and secure themselves with their doors open.

Thus doors remaining open at the main lobby reduces the time between an emergency being triggered and the final state being reached - (i.e. zero time)

Comment: The fire safety issue is well made.

Comment: I'd like to see some back-up for the claims made here, personally. It sounds *plausible* but I don't know how much a difference elevator doors are going to make to the movement of gases (they're nothing like air-tight, after all) nor does this answer firmly establish that this benefit was the primary one on designers' minds.

Comment: @KRyan I'd like to see that myself too! :) Yes this is speculation - but only after reading around the topic. I was hoping that there might be more mention of saftey and fire issues in other answers, but not as yet. Wish I know an SME on elevators!

Comment: That latter one also makes sense: what better way to tell first responders that no persons are stuck in an elevator between floors than to have them all sit in the lobby with their doors open?

Comment: In my country, and I assume many others... lifts get disabled when fire breaks out.. it's linked in with the fire alarm.  You have to use the stairs.

Comment: @matt That's right - which is why I stressed that this scenario was relevant *prior* to emergency procedures being triggered - or indeed, possibly even *failing* to trigger!

Comment: @Matt: Yes, and typically lifts are disabled by automatically going to the egress level (bottom floor), opening the doors, and are then stuck (secured) there with the doors open.

Answer (score 22):

It's simple math.

Let's say a building has 10 floors.

Leaving the doors open on the floor the elevator is on benefits 1 floor out of 10 as it reduces the time to enter the elevator.

But it lengthens the time to enter the elevator on 9 out of 10 floors as those floors now need to wait for the elevator doors to close before it can start moving.

As such, this would only benefit 10% of the people in the building at any given time but--even more important--inconvenient 90% of the people at any given time.

That's just bad UX.

Comment: Assuming an apartment building and evening time when most of the people get back from work it would make sense for the elevator to always return to the first floor (some elevators do this already) and open the doors.

Answer (score 22):

From a user's perspective, the open door would also seem to be an invitation to get into the elevator.  During the elapsed time of getting into the elevator, it could be called from another floor, causing the doors to close and at which point the boarding passenger thinks *Wow!  What a convenient and smart elevator!*.

But, instead of going down to the lobby, suddenly they are on their way up to the penthouse because the calling floor button press had already occurred a few seconds earlier.

Comment: Good point although (in the UK at least) if it is called, that floor button lights up.

Comment: I think this might be the best reason on the page.  There are a lot of good reasons listed, but the race condition that leads to the user going "Wait, where am I going?" is probably the one that would most cause people to dislike open elevators.

Comment: Why would the passenger think the elevator is smart if it started moving before the person had told it where to go? I would think "oh crud, it's going somewhere I probably don't want to go", which has happened to me several times, even with elevators that habitually close their doors on idle. This already happens even with such elevators. I don't think having the doors stay open would change this much, except for people used to door-closing elevators who may have misconceptions of how they work.

Comment: The doors starting to close would be the impetus behind thinking that the elevator was smart.  But, once it started moving, the passenger would realize the gig is up (or down).  ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Elevators actually do have an option to stay on a floor and leave the doors open - that's what they do in service mode.  But it also makes it ignore the call buttons outside the elevator.

It is a huge time saver for people moving in/out of an apartment building - the elevator will always stay with it's doors open on the current floor, and only close them when you select a floor on the panel inside the elevator.  That gives the movers plenty of time to move things, and keeps the elevator ready for them for the next trip.  In this case it's safe to assume they will be making a lot of trips from the ground floor to floor X, and back again.

But for normal operation, it's usually a better assumption that the next user will be on a different floor, and close the doors to be ready to move to them.

Comment: To expand on this, an open door acts as an indicator that an elevator is in "service mode", and that you should take the other one to avoid inconveniencing the movers.

Comment: @Mark except that's a terrible indicator. If a person encounters open elevator doors, they just walk in and choose a floor. :)

Comment: @DA01 Yes, and they will quickly realize that the elevator isn't working properly.  There is usually a trick to getting an elevator to operate once it is in service mode.  For instance, you might have to hold a specific button or a specific combination of buttons.

Comment: @cimmanon that sounds even more frustrating! :)

Answer (score 8):

If an elevator is sitting idle on some floor with the doors open, then the time required to respond to a service request on that floor will be reduced, but the time required to respond to a service request elsewhere will be increased.  In a building with multiple elevators, it may sometimes be possible to have one elevator sitting open at the main floor without impeding responsiveness elsewhere if other elevators are better positioned to handle requests from elsewhere.

Even in that situation, however, having the door stay open may not improve the user experience.  If a door opens in response to a button push, a user may enter the elevator with confidence that the door isn't going to close instantly.  By contrast, if a user arrives at an elevator and sees the door open, the user may have no idea how long the door will remain open.  This may cause some anxiety which would have been avoided had the door been closed prior to user actions.

Further, time which elapses between a user's request and the start of the system's visible response is often more noticeable than time which elapses during the system's response.  If the user pushes a button and the door starts to open 100ms later, users will perceive that the door opened instantly, even if three more seconds elapse before they can actually enter.  Users will not perceive that the system cost them three seconds by not having opened the doors sooner.  If having to close the doors before servicing a request from another floor adds three seconds to that other request, that three seconds is apt to be far more noticeable.

Finally, as noted elsewhere, if users do not expect elevator doors to stay open unless held, users are unlikely to act in ways which could pose a hazard if doors close unexpectedly.  If doors are expected to close soon after they open, passengers who step out of an elevator will be inclined to immediately ensure that all of their luggage and associated straps are fully clear of the door.  If doors often stay open, a passenger who isn't certain of where to go after arriving at a floor might step away for a moment to look at a map while a luggage strap is dangling across the threshold.  In such a case, the doors might close on the strap, and the departing elevator might tear it off.

Answer (score 6):

As with many other things, the answer probably lies in the possible failure modes.

Let us consider what can go wrong in various bad cases, when the doors are open, and when they are closed.

1) A loss of suspension. A cable snaps.

Doors open: you now have a gaping pit.

Doors closed: you now have closed doors that will not open again until the cage rises back to that level.

2) A fire alarm is hit.

Doors open: everyone piles into the elevator out of habit. This is about the most dangerous place to be in a fire, and, since elevators are disabled at this point, also the least effective escape route. You could simply close the doors in event of fire, to prevent this... but that risks trapping people inside the elevator.

Doors closed: nobody enters the elevator, because nobody can.

But there's also the matter of efficiency and responsiveness...

3) Someone attempts to enter the elevator just as someone on another floor summons it.

Doors open: the elevator responds immediately, closing the doors in the face of the passenger, as it has no idea they exist; or the elevator sounds a warning buzzer for a time, then closes the door, hence saving no time (and indeed, losing time if there was nobody there).

Doors closed: the elevator waits a while, as a button was pressed in order to open the doors on this floor.

4) Someone on another floor requests this elevator, with nobody on this floor.

Doors open: Time to respond = door-closing time, plus transit time, plus door-opening time.

Doors closed: Time to respond = transit time, plus door-opening time.

5) Someone on this floor requests this elevator.

Doors open: Time to respond = zero.

Doors closed: Time to respond = door-opening time.

Given 3, 4 and 5, unless 5 is in the significant majority of cases (such as on the ground floor) it is more efficient to have the doors closed. Having the doors closed on another floor also permits the idle elevator to move to the ground floor and open its doors there.
The ground floor is not subject to the safety issues outlined above.

Comment: The fire alarm case does not stand up. The lift is closed. People want to take the lift but it is disabled. Now, if the lift is open, people want to take the lift but it is disabled. The situation is the same.

Comment: Actually, in the fire alarm case, *the lift being closed adds danger*. Someone can be trapped inside !

Comment: For the cases 3), 4) and 5), both behaviours are equivalent. The delay is just transferred from one passenger to the other passenger.

Comment: @Nicolas, I'm afraid I disagree.
- standing inside the most dangerous place in the building is not an equivalent UX to standing *out*side the most dangerous place in the building, separated from it by metal fireproof doors. Plunging to your death in a flaming fireball is not a similar UX to waiting for the elevator.
- Disabling the "open door" button inside the elevator would be strange UX design: no reason to be trapped.
- having a door slam in your face then waiting time T to enter is not the same UX as having it start closed and waiting time T. So transfer of time between people matters.

Answer (score 5):

There are two programming modes where an elevator *will* stay open on a floor:

1. **"Independent Service"** mode.  This is activated by turning a key on the car's panel.  In this mode, the car detaches itself from the system's programming if there are multiple elevators in the bank, and remains open on that floor.  While at rest, the car cannot be called from another floor.  To close the door, someone must enter the car and *hold down* a floor button until the door is completely closed.  At that point it will travel to the selected floor, and the doors will remain open there.  Independent Service mode is primarily used for building maintenance, moving, etc.
2. **"Peak Up"** mode.  This is programmed into the system as a whole, and typically used when there are a good number of elevators in the bank.  In Peak Up mode, the system always tries to return one or more cars to the main floor (typically a Lobby) when none are in use, and will usually open the door.  This is typically configured for a time of the day when many people are expected to be entering a building, such as the beginning of the day for an office, or the end of the day for a hotel.

Comment: While this is certainly interesting information, it doesn't actually answer the question that was posed as to why they close.

Comment: Also apropos of nothing, some elevators have a hands-free mode for the Jewish Sabbath. They stop at each floor in turn, allowing the faithful to (eventually) reach their destination without actually operating machinery.

Comment: @Eric - Is this a joke ?! Where do such lifts exist ? In order to avoid "working" on sabbat day, this would spend much more work - in the sense of physics. With a huge waste of energy, for a much less efficient system.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - No, no joke. Cedars Sinai Hospital in Los Angeles has one - I've seen it myself. It takes *quite* a bit longer to get where you're going in such an elevator, so it's definitely not about efficiency. The whole point is to maintain the faithful's access to the upper floors of a building during their holy day. [Of course, Wikipedia has an article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat_elevator)

Answer (score 3):

While there's merit to the safety and efficiency-related perspective (in fact, those reasons are likely *why* elevators do this), from a **UX perspective** there's a much more important reason for keeping elevator doors closed while waiting, even if all other considerations were removed.

It's about **setting expectations** to provide a good experience.

We all [hate waiting](http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/4615S13/Psychology_of_Waiting_Lines.pdf) and will always be disappointed when we learn that we have to wait. By forcing a user to push the call button before serving an open elevator cab, you defer the that initial disappointment (i.e. you don't see see the closed elevator from down the hallway and immediately experience the disappointment of your impending wait.)

Additionally, by forcing (and controlling) that initial interaction, you can continue to [manage reasonable expectations](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/01/14/your-money/the-importance-of-setting-expectations-whether-high-or-low.html?pagewanted=all). If a rider encounters an elevator ready for them to waltz right into, that's a statistical payoff. But people don't think in statistics: just as with game or task design, [expectancy theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectancy_theory) tells us that one payoff or "near hit" is enough to keep expectations high for a while. The downside here is that a user has a negative impression from all subsequent experiences that fall below the expectation.

Additionally, the further the reality of an outcome is from the expectation, the greater the effect will be, and [humans hate losing more than they enjoy gaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion). Having a controlled interaction point allows you to enforce a minimum wait that reduces the deviation in wait times and produces a smaller perceived loss for relatively longer waits, again managing expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's mainly tradition, but all the other the reasons listed in the answers are incentive not to change it. That being said--here's one more reason. (I'd comment if I could.)

If you walk into an open elevator wanting to go down, someone might press the call button on a floor above you before you press the number you want to go to, forcing you to ride the elevator all the way up before going down. If there's only one elevator that's fine--but if there are two you really should be able to both get in different elevators.

Note that this isn't an issue if you're on the lowest or highest floor.

Comment: This case is interesting. But it can be solved with a presence detector - which would probably be used anyway for the light.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that hasn't been mentioned. A small pet such as a cat or mouse who manages to escape from an apartment could run towards an open elevator and fall down the small gap between the open elevator doors and the elevator. What a terrible way to die!